# Converting RDD to spark data frames in python and then accessing a particular values of columns

Tags: pyspark

I want to access values of a particular column from a data sets that I've read from a csv file. The datasets are stored in pyspark RDD which I want to be converted into the DataFrame.
I am using the below code :

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlc=SQLContext(sc)
df=sc.textFile(r'D:\Home\train.csv')
df=sqlc.createDataFrame(df)
```

but it is showing error:

```
Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>
```

First 2 rows of df are :

```
['"id","product_uid","product_title","search_term","relevance"',
 '2,100001,"Simpson Strong-Tie 12-Gauge Angle","angle bracket",3']
```

I think the first row is creating this problem. Moreover I want to create data frame which stores the values from 2nd row to last.(Not the first row because it will be the header). How can I achieve this ? I've searched for it but could not find any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of spark are you using ?

Comment: @eliasah I am using spark 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

To read a csv file to spark dataframe you should use spark-csv. 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('cars.csv')
```

**How to use spark csv**
If you are using pyspark directly from the terminal. Instead of calling

```
$SPARKHOME/bin/pyspark
```

You have to use

```
$SPARKHOME/bin/pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0
```

and then use the code above.

If you are using ipython + findspark, you'll have to modify your PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS (before starting ipython)

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS=--master local[4] --packages "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0" pyspark-shell
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use them with pyspark in windows ?
I am new to pyspark btw.

Comment: It's not really much different in Windows. The arguments to pyspark are still the same, you'll just have a slightly different way of setting the suggested environment variable. Possibly check [this question](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/how-to-run-a-pyspark-application-in-windows-8-command-prompt) for more, or post a separate question about running pyspark under Windows.

Comment: I am using iPython with spark, do I have to create an environment variable PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS ? And whenever I start pyspark using the following command :
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0  
and then use 'sc' then it shows spark is not defined. But normally when I start pyspark, it does not show any error regarding 'sc'.